Aleph fixed points = Beth fixed points?
Consider a cardinal number $\kappa = \aleph_\lambda = \beth_\gamma$.
Under the assumption $\beth_\gamma = \gamma$ I can show that $\lambda = \gamma$ und $\aleph_\lambda = \lambda$. In other words: A fixed point of $\beth$ is also a fixed point of $\aleph$.
Now consider $\aleph_\lambda = \lambda$. Can one show, that $\lambda = \gamma$ and $\beth_\gamma = \gamma$ or is this direction wrong?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I reformulated my question.

This is independent of ZFC.
If GCH holds, then $\aleph_\alpha=\beth_\alpha$ for every ordinal $\alpha$.
On the other hand, suppose that we're in a model $V$ of GCH and let $\lambda$ be the least fixed point of the $\aleph$ function, so $\aleph_\lambda=\lambda$. Force with $\text{Add}(\omega,\lambda^+)$, which is ccc hence preserves all cardinals and so $\lambda$ remains a fixed point of the $\aleph$ function in the generic extension. On the other hand, letting $G$ be the generic filter,
$$
\beth_\lambda^{V[G]}\ge \left(2^{\aleph_0}\right)^{V[G]}\ge \lambda^+>\lambda
$$
(note that $\lambda^+$ is the same whether computed in $V$ or $V[G]$, so no superscript is needed). In particular, $\lambda$ is not a fixed point of $\beth$ in $V[G]$.

This violates the requirement that the cardinal remains on the $\beth$ sequence, though.

The answer is no. Fix some countable sequence $\alpha_n$ whose limit is the first $\aleph$ fixed point. Say that $\sf GCH$ holds in the ground model, we can have $\beth_n=\aleph_{\alpha_n}^+$, so the first $\aleph$ fixed point is now $\beth_\omega$, which is definitely not a fixed point.
